# Is their any way to fetch duplicates from AD using java

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap

Is their any way to fetch duplicates from AD using java ? I see we can do it in power shell by grouping all usernames and then checking count >1.

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Find-Active-Directory-c8789b42

Please help :).

Answer (score 0):

you should get all objects of a special type(such as user, group , ...) and their attributes. then check duplicate attributes of all objects. for do this, you can insert each attributes in a hasp map as a key, and insert all value of attribute per each object and check is duplicated or not ?

use JAVA JNDI to access AD server as follow:

```
/**
 *  retrieve all attributes of a named object.
 * 
 */
class GetAllAttrs {
  static void printAttrs(Attributes attrs) {
    if (attrs == null) {
      System.out.println("No attributes");
    } else {
      /* Print each attribute */
      try {
        for (NamingEnumeration ae = attrs.getAll(); ae.hasMore();) {
          Attribute attr = (Attribute) ae.next();
          System.out.println("attribute: " + attr.getID());

          /* print each value */
          for (NamingEnumeration e = attr.getAll(); e.hasMore(); System.out
              .println("value: " + e.next()))
            ;
        }
      } catch (NamingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Set up the environment for creating the initial context
    Hashtable<String, Object> env = new Hashtable<String, Object>(11);
    env
        .put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
            "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://localhost:389/o=JNDITutorial");

    try {
      // Create the initial context
      DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);

      // Get all the attributes of named object
      Attributes answer = ctx.getAttributes("cn=Ted Geisel, ou=People");

      // Print the answer
      printAttrs(answer);

      // Close the context when we're done
      ctx.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

also you can use search filter to limit your outputs:

```
public class LdapSearch {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Hashtable env = new Hashtable();

    String sp = "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory";
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, sp);

    String ldapUrl = "ldap://localhost:389/dc=yourName, dc=com";
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, ldapUrl);

    DirContext dctx = new InitialDirContext(env);

    String base = "ou=People";

    SearchControls sc = new SearchControls();
    String[] attributeFilter = { "cn", "mail" };
    sc.setReturningAttributes(attributeFilter);
    sc.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);

    String filter = "(&(sn=W*)(l=Criteria*))";

    NamingEnumeration results = dctx.search(base, filter, sc);
    while (results.hasMore()) {
      SearchResult sr = (SearchResult) results.next();
      Attributes attrs = sr.getAttributes();

      Attribute attr = attrs.get("cn");
      System.out.print(attr.get() + ": ");
      attr = attrs.get("mail");
      System.out.println(attr.get());
    }
    dctx.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: I will test it. But if we have millions of records and it will be very slow as well as it not feasible to fetch whole active directory. In softtera LDAP browser or any other client you can use SQL queries to get this output. Any Java API providing this features ?

Comment: You can filter your search on AD to prevent get all objects or attributes, try to user search filter. I add s search example to end of above code.